# How to calculate all the possible divisions in a list?

Tags: prolog

I found this predicate for the calculation of all possible sums.

```
subset_sum(0,[],[]).

subset_sum(N,[_|Xs],L) :-
    subset_sum(N,Xs,L).

subset_sum(N,[X|Xs],[X|Rest]) :-
    R is N-X,
    subset_sum(R,Xs,Rest).
```

Knowing that the division does not have the commutative property, how do I get the same result for the division?

This predicate only works for the division between the two elements and in order.

```
subset_div(1,[],[]).

subset_div(N,[_|Xs],L) :-
    subset_div(N,Xs,L).

subset_div(N,[X|Xs],[X|Rest]) :-
    R is X/N,
    subset_div(R,Xs,Rest).
```

how you can get this result?

```
?-subset_div(20,[10,100,90,3,5],L).
    L=[100,5].

?-subset_div(5,[10,4,59,200,12],L).
    L=[200,10,4].
```

5= (200/10)/4 or 5 = (200/4)/10 but 5 \= (4/200)/10 or 5\= (10/4)/200

Thanks.

Comment: Could you extend your question ? I don't understand how `4` get in the result.

Comment: @CapelliC `(200/10)/4 = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in terms of a product if you only care about left-associative solutions.  Solutions when you can do, say [20 / (10 / 2) / 5] are harder, and would require a more complicated output format.

```
subset_prod(1, [], []).

subset_prod(N, [_|Xs], L) :-
    subset_prod(N, Xs, L).

subset_prod(N, [X|Xs], [X|Rest]) :-
    R is N/X,
    subset_prod(R, Xs, Rest).

subset_div1(N, [X|Xs], [X|L]) :-
    X1 is X / N,
    integer(X1),
    subset_prod(X1, Xs, L).

subset_div1(N, [_|Xs], L) :-
    subset_div(N, Xs, L).

subset_div(N, L, M) :-
    sort(L, L1),
    reverse(L1, L2),
    subset_div1(N, L2, M).
```

Comment: This works nice (+1). I wanted to make it work for `gprolog` but, interestingly, gprolog's `integer` predicate works a little differently (fails on `R is 20/4, integer(R)` for example), so I replaced the `R is N/X` with `R is N // X, Y is R * N, N = Y` and similarly for `X1 is X/N`. That works in gprolog and swi-prolog.

Comment: Thanks!  I haven't used gprolog for a long time.  It's sad that builtins are not portable.